# how can i update two model table fields at one request in django rest api

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

i have two tables called user and address. the address table have a foreign key relation with the user table. so how access the fields of both table and update it in a single request call

```
{
    "first_name": "abijith",
    "last_name": "manu",
    "profile_picture": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/profile_pictures/my_pic_RxnXQ6n.jpg",
    "date_of_birth": "2024-02-16",
    "username": "",
    "gender": "male",
    "email": "doc@gmail.com",
    "phone_number": "7306986870",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "street": "xvsvf",
            "city": "sss",
            "state": "ssss",
            "country": "ggggggggg",
            "zip_code": "sssssss"
        }
    ]
```

this is the sample form of response that i want. and i have to update the filed as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive those thigs using nested serializer

#### serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['street', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'zip_code']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    addresses = AddressSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_picture', 'date_of_birth', 'username', 'gender', 'email', 'phone_number', 'addresses']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        addresses_data = validated_data.pop('addresses')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for address_data in addresses_data:
            Address.objects.create(user=user, **address_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        addresses_data = validated_data.pop('addresses')
        instance = super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        # Assuming you don't want to add new addresses, but update existing ones
        for address_data in addresses_data:
            address_instance = instance.addresses.get(pk=address_data.get('id'))
            AddressSerializer().update(address_instance, address_data)

        return instance
```

### views.py

```
class UserUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: the date of the address are not updating when i am passing data from the frontend


formData.append(`addresses[${addressId}][city]`, event.target.city.value);
formData.append(`addresses[${addressId}][state]`, event.target.state.value);
formData.append(`addresses[${addressId}][country]`, event.target.country.value);
formData.append(`addresses[${addressId}][zip_code]`, event.target.zip_code.value);

 const res = await axios.put(baseUrl + `auth/doc/list/${id}`, formData, {headers: {
 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',

Comment: Put code of models in question for batter answer